# How can I define every 1 hour plus half in crontab?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

Here is my current command:

```
*/30 */1 * * * wget http://mywebsite.com
```

But it doesn't work as expected. Expected period is every 90min. How can I do that?

Noted that this doesn't work either:

```
*/90 * * * * wget http://mywebsite.com
```

Answer (score 3):

To run crontab job in every 90 minute we need to actually execute two task

1)start a task at 00 and execute it every 3 hour

2)execute a task and run it at every one and half our
After then we can achieve our goal

1st line will run at 00:00, 03:00, 06:00 hours etc. 
2nd line will run at 01:30, 04:30, 07:30 etc

00 0-21/3  * * *  wget http://mywebsite.com

30 1-22/3  * * *  wget http://mywebsite.com